# Refresh the parent window from the second child window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window.open, window.opener

The work flow is like this, from my page, I created a popup using `window.open` method, then open other popup from that window and close its immediate parent, and I need to refresh the first parent page from this popup. I tried in different ways, but the `window.opener` method  can't get the parent windows property.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: What browser and version are you using?